# Streaming windows mobile 10 to Xbox One/TV

Tags: streaming

Is it possible?
I'd have to watch a football match from a windows mobile app.
How can I stream my Lumia 640XL to my TV (I have also an Xbox One)?
For example, chromecast would work?

Answer (score -1):

App which you use should have that options for streaming. We have some apps which can stream on smart tv.. Exmp. Tube Cast is that app. So check does you have that option in your app.

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question?

Comment: If app have option for streaming then you can if it's not you can't